# wm/am not found from adb shell

Tags: android, adb, dpi

Phone: OnePlus 3t. Rooted. No updates.
Booting problems, so adb started from TWRP recovery screen.

Whether I enter "wm size reset" or "am size display-reset", it is telling me "/sbin/sh/: wm: not found" or "/sbin/sh: am: not found" respectively. 
If I try it in TWRP terminal I get the same, except "sh:" instead of "/sbin/sh/:".

First time using adb tools, so I could be doing something basic wrong. 
Can't use phone until I manage to fix the resolution issue. Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

That is because TWRP has no screen management. The use of certain commands in TWRP is restricted and limited.

am stands for activity manager, which is a process from the Android Operating System, but when you start on recovery mode not every layer of the OS is started.

I hope it helps.